# Euclidian vector space $(V,\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle)$: be $\langle f(v),v \rangle = 0$ then $f = 0$

Tags: vector-spaces

I am trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

In a Euclidian vector space $(V,\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle)$, be $f \in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$ with $\langle f(v),v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$. Then $f = 0$.

I am not looking for the full proof or disproof but for pointers how to understand this and maybe a few tips how I could go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What if $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $f$ is a rotation of $\frac\pi2$ radians around the origin?

Comment: Ah, I think I understood this, thank you! Does something similar still apply when we are talking about $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. And no, on $\Bbb C$ this doesn't work.